# Pphunit keeps giving error: [1049] Unknown database ':memory:'

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpunit

I just started working with phpunit in Laravel 7. I run into a problem that I cannot find a solution for. I am using Laravel 7 with Xampp.

```
My phpunit.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpcd ..
         cdit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

My test function:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;


use Tests\TestCase;

class ThreadsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function test_a_user_can_browse_threads()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/threads');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

When I run phpunit (vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit) I get this:

> ```
> PHPUnit 8.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .E                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)
>
> Time: 1.57 seconds, Memory: 20.00 MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Tests\Feature\ThreadsTest::test_a_user_can_browse_threads
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ':memory:' (SQL:
> ```
>
> SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> ```
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:631
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:339
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php:99
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php:48
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\WipeCommand.php:69
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\WipeCommand.php:46
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:33
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:37
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:91
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:35
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:592
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:134
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:258
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:121
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:56
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:28
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\FreshCommand.php:41
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:33
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:37
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:91
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:35
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:592
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:134
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:258
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:121
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:911
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:264
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:140
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:93
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:185
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:263
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Testing\PendingCommand.php:171
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Testing\PendingCommand.php:291
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithConsole.php:52
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations.php:16
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:119
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:84
>
> Caused by
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ':memory:'
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:46
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php:24
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:184
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:926
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:961
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:405
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:331
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:631
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:339
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php:99
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php:48
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\WipeCommand.php:69
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\WipeCommand.php:46
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:33
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:37
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:91
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:35
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:592
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:134
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:258
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:121
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:56
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:28
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\FreshCommand.php:41
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:33
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:37
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:91
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:35
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:592
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:134
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:258
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:121
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:911
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:264
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:140
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:93
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:185
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:263
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Testing\PendingCommand.php:171
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Testing\PendingCommand.php:291
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithConsole.php:52
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations.php:16
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:119
> C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:84
>
> ERRORS!
> Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
> ```

Also the tables in my MYSQL database are all deleted.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Comment: Changing Mysql to Sqlite seems to solve the problem. But I do not understand why. As far as I know I do not have Sqlite on my machine! Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to run `sqlite` as a memory database, at least that is my preferred test setup.

To achieve this, you have to setup your env in testing like so. Right now you had the connection as `Mysql`, this can not use the memory setting as `sqlite`.

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Comment: if you like me want to set to mysql , should changed it to      <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>